# Black screen while using bluestacks

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bluestacks

I was using android apps using blue-stacks app player from more than two months. Yesterday when I started blue-stacks it started but after 2-3 min screen gone black I waited for 10-15 min but nothing happened. and then I shutdown my laptop using power button.

When I started again the screen flickers for  1-2 seconds and gone black it seems the laptop is on but screen is black. I tried many times by force shut down and starting the laptop but nothing happened. then I took out the battery waited for 2-3 hours and inserted it again and started my laptop it started fine.

I was thinking that it may be due to some bad apps so I again I started the blue-stacks to uninstall the recent apps as I opened blue-stacks it happened again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade your graphics driver and restart your machine.

Comment: I installed the latest driver for my ATI Raedon 5470 and I think problem is gone. I have not encountered that problem since when I installed new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check your graphics driver. Only download Bluestacks from the original vendor.(too many sites are providing fake ones)

Answer (score 0):

Black screen after a minute or two? (loading Clash of Clans, for example)

This worked for me: Install a settings app and turn off sleep timer.

I set mine to never sleep and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The below method solved this problem for me:

1. Click on settings button (located top right of the window),
2. From the left menu navigate to the Engine tab and,
3. From the top-right, in 'Choose graphic mode', click on 'DirectX' then,
4. Click on 'Restart now'.