# Sony Vaio (VPCEB34EN) won't boot, Shows black screen Power LED stays Green

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, sony-vaio

I was using my laptop (Vaio VPCEB34EN) yesterday and shut down after work. When I started again it was showing black screen only Power button light was showing. Even it didn't show the BIOS.I waited for some time then I forcefully turned off and tried again but nothing happened. then I took of battery for 10 min and tried again and now I am stuck with this.

First time I faced this problem when I was [using Bluestacks](https://superuser.com/questions/838462/black-screen-while-using-bluestacks) (suddenly screen gone black) then I took of battery waited for some time and inserted and this worked. after that I installed the latest driver for my ATI Graphics and it was working fine from two days and now I got this problem.

**What I tried :**

1. Removed battery and waited for 2-3 hours and put it back.
2. Checked with external LCD Screen but showing nothing.
3. Checked with direct power using adapter (without battery).

I searched lots of articles on Google and it seems that it is problem due to Video Card. Does it means my Motherboard has gone?

**Update 1:** 
I gave my laptop to repairing shop and they fixed it. They told that the problem was due to **Graphics Chip**. and they told that they did **Reballing** of Video Chip, charged thousand rupees (Indian Currency) it worked fine and now it is running as before.

**Update 2:**
It worked about 15 days without any problem after that now I am facing the same problem again.I gave the laptop to the same shop they clearly didn't specified why the problem is coming but they told to change the motherboard. Please suggest What Should I do now?

**Update 3 :** I gave my laptop to **Sony Service Center** and they fixed it. They told that the problem was due to **LCD Cable**. and they told that they have changed the old one and now I am guessing that I was fooled previous time when I gave it to the earlier shop. I don't know for how many days but now it is working fine.

**Update 4 :** Well, as I was guessing the problem was not solved it happened again after one month and gave my laptop to **Sony Service Center** and they said that You **Mother-board** has gone bad. and it will costs up Rs. 13000 near about.

**Update 5** I did some internet research and done some experiments on my motherboard. I took my motherboard out and heated using Hot Air Gun for 30-50 Seconds and then I fixed in the laptop. **Now Laptop is working good using external monitor but Laptop LCD display still goes blank. Please somebody tell me is it motherboard or LCD problem ?**

Answer (score 1):

I've passed through this sometimes and it seems in your case that the **graphics card could be broken**.

If the Laptop seems to run normally except for the screen and you connect to a screen with VGA/DVI and see nothing, yes, the issue is probably the graphics card.

It is a laptop so you're not able to change any hardware except the RAM or Hard Disk, so it seems your laptop is almost dead.

I have an uncle that has a repair shop and sometimes, when the laptop seems to be lost as this, he open the laptop and give some heat (90-120 ºC) to the motherboard trying to *randomly* fix/rebuild any kind of broken wieldings. He recover laptops  with a 65-70% of success.

**This is not a formal solution, just a *give-it-a-try* before you dump the laptop**

Answer (score 0):

## Solutions!!!

-Updating Graphic card driver
-Updating BIOS to latest version

or for other solutions,  visit Official Microsoft forum -
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/black-screen-after-sleep-mode-windows-8/d759b75d-4784-4a82-bf48-a1cb78275db3

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three steps:

1. Remove all external like battery,power,pendrive etc and press start
   upto 30-50sec then connect all external and try start press shift+F8
   .IF IT not work.
2. Remove or replace ram and try to start system.
   check if it not work.
3. Take last option but in this condition u have
   some face another problem like when you press f2 your BIOS asking its
   manufacturing password. If you ready then read first of all remove
   all accessories like battery, hardisk, RAM and open its back cover
   then disconnect its board battery upto 30-50 min and connect part on
   its place without hardisk. Press start button withh F2 key and if it
   work then ok or not work then f9 to reset in default after that
   press F10 to exit at last start windows normally.

Comment: Have u read the complete question ? It's working with external monitor/lcd but nothing shows in laptop lcd.